# How to make TypeScript infer the type of dynamic new() calls

Tags: typescript, type-inference

I am dynamically creating subclasses and I would like the factory function to know the subclass's return type.

I can do it with a cast but I would like to know if there's a way to infer it without requiring a cast.

```
class Hello { 
  a = 1;
}

class Hello2 extends Hello{ 
  b = 2; 
}

class Hello3 extends Hello { 
  c = 3; 
}

function create<T extends typeof Hello>(ctor: T): InstanceType<T> {
  // If I don't cast this, it won't compile
  return new ctor() as InstanceType<T>;
}

// Fails as it should because it's not a constructor of the right type
const h1 = create(Number);
const h2 = create(Hello2); 
console.log(h2.b); // no error
const h3 = create(Hello3);
console.log(h3.c); // no error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What, if you instead make the class instance generic (not the static side/constructor function)? That should work out for you, like [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=22&ssc=31&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEASCmIQHtoG9oChrTNAvNAIwDcmAvppqJDAksgEzTwAeALvAHYAmdiKDNmgAjAtEYkslauChwByAMwsO3PgobosOYOKVSKVAGYBXLsHYBLZF2jAATvDCcAPABVVnXvwYA+AApLZAcALmgueAB3AIBKAj9od3i0YSd2Uwc7SKj7dhC4o0wAemLoADEwKxAYSGgrdmgIAAtkUxAeUXhgMFMIeHr2AHIYLmRGvGBbCHYHU2CHaGRjaHZmgYcrAHNmxuppxuaicUdnTgCAOVMAWxF4B1iyKa4Z6GbmQlOXeAD6FEZHlhnhBkCB4AA6FBbALvcEiQGlCKoe4OEL7F6HFSfJzfX6KJSPdEgsGQ5DQ5pKcHABFlMYsByohxAA):

```
class Hello { 
  a = 1;
}

class Hello2 extends Hello{ 
  b = 2; 
}

class Hello3 extends Hello { 
  c = 3; 
}

function create<T extends Hello>(ctor: new() => T) {
  return new ctor()
}

const h1 = create(Number); // error
const h2 = create(Hello2); // h2: Hello2
console.log(h2.b); // no error
const h3 = create(Hello3); // h3: Hello3
console.log(h3.c); // no error
```

If needed, you could define additional arguments to be passed like `create<T extends Hello>(ctor: new(...args: any[]) => T)` or in a more specific manner.

Comment: Sounds promising, I don't understand why mine doesn't work, but let me give it a try with my actual code.

Comment: Your example definitely goes in the right direction and is rather limited by the compiler's inability to make assumptions about conditional types (`InstanceType` is one) in combination with unresolved generic type parameters (`T`). Such a constellation almost always makes a type assertion necessary. If you write it like above, you can leave out the conditional type and it will be typed properly again.

Comment: The problem with this approach would be that I would have to duplicate the signature of `Hello`, which in my case requires specific parameters, if I want type-safety there. I can always make it `any...` which would be a trade-off, an `any` instead of a `cast` and I think a cast would be safer. Having said that, this definitely answers the question as it was asked.

Comment: I thought of not duplicating the params using `ConstructorParams` but I haven't been able to figure out how to use it. I'll post a question later about that. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1501

Comment: `ConstructorParams` would lead to a similar problem, as it is also a cond. type. You would need to make it generic on the params of the subclass to be instantiated (or all classes have same params). Whether type assertion or not, I would choose what is most easily achievable in this case. In the end the assertions are not a bad thing (that statement from a former Java dev ;), as it is well encapsulated inside the `create` function and the caller of the function doesn't have to bother. You could implement runtime checks, if you wanted or later on replace the casts, if TS should get smarter.